# Disable specific date on React-datepicker

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, datepicker

how are you?
This is my first post in Stack Overflow, i have a problem and i hope someone of you could help me.

I am working on a project, and the former developers have used a react datapicker for this project, and the project managers want to keep it, but i want to disable some dates.
What i want to do is to give a list of dates to disable, for example i want to disable 1st May 2021 and 4th June 2021.

The datapicker is this one : https://reactnicedates.hernansartorio.com/

They only show how to disable a date in a week for example all saturdays but i don't know how to do to desactivate many dates.

Comment: You can add a custom disabled method the the modifiers property. In the example on their website they use `disabled: date => getDay(date) === 6, // Disables Saturdays` which as example disables all saturdays, but you can write another check to disable whatever date(s) you like

Comment: Thank you for your reply, can you show me if you want to desactivate 2 dates for example how you do please?

Answer (score 0):

You can make your custom modifiers like below and pass it into data picker

```
const [disabledDates, setDisabledData] = useState(['01/05/2021', '04/06/2021']);

const modifiers = {
  disabled: date => disabledDates.includes(date) // assuming date variable have same format as 'dd/mm/yyyy'
}
```

Note:- Remember to check format of both dates. If format is different than condition will not work.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but even if i set the dates in the same format it doesn't work..


const [disabledDates, setDisabledData] = useState([new Date(2021, 5, 1).getTime(), new Date(2021, 5, 4).getTime()]);

  const modifiers = {
    disabled: (date) => {
      disabledDates.includes(date.getTime())
    }
  }

Comment: can you share more of your code in codesandbox example so we can take better look?

Comment: Of course, there is the link of my sandbox : https://codesandbox.io/s/javascript-forked-dos6m?file=/index.js:0-606

Comment: here I have updated correct format for date you can check this codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-nice-dates-xstio?file=/src/App.js